# DateField always return None value

Tags: python, django

```
class News(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  full_text = models.TextField()
  pub_date = models.DateField('-pub_date')
```

then i run
python manage.py shell
whatever i do value for News.pub_date is None

i am using sqlite3 and when i open database i could see that date values are there. but when i recover an object pub_date is None. I dont reveive any error after
s=News.objects.all()[0].pub_date

```
>>> from face.models import News
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s=News()
>>> s.pub_date

>>> s=News()
>>> s.title="hgello"
>>> s.full_text="hello there"
>>> s.pub_date = datetime.now()
>>> s.show=True
>>> s.save()
>>> t=News.objects.all()
>>> t
[<News: This is title>, <News: second text>, <News: sample>, <News: hgello>]
>>> t=t[3]
>>> print t.pub_date
    None
```

**I have solved the issue. i just deleted database file of sqllite3. I think it happened becouse initially it was named DateTimeField and then I changed it to DateField. But i did syncdb in between of changes. So django was able successfully store date data but cannot recover. And re-syncdb didnt help i did it several times. only phisycal delete of database and recreation structure of database solved the usue.
**

Comment: You seem to be confusing queries and specifying a model. What are you trying to achieve with `'-pub_date'` there?

Comment: What is `-pub_date` in the arguments?

Comment: you can ignore this -pub_date it suppose to be column name in database as parameter for DateField object

Comment: Then use the `db_column` keyword. Do not assume it's always the first parameter.

Comment: add print s.pub_date after `>>> s.pub_date = datetime.now()` and show output

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to set the [`auto_now_add` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField):

```
pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Alternatively, you could override the `.save()` method:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    full_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.today()
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: auto_now_add may be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it shoud be `auto_now_add`.