# peewee DateField property is None with MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

Via `pwiz` on my MySQL database, I get:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Pub(BaseModel):
    ...
    author = TextField(null=True)
    ...
    publish_date = DateField(null=True)
    ...
```

Then, when iterating `entry in Pub.select()`, `entry.publish_date` is always `None`, although all entries in the database have the date set (or at least part of it, such as year, i.e. an entry like `2016-00-00`).

(There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089590/datefield-always-return-none-value) but that problem is different: it is not set, and thus the solution was `auto_now_add`.)

Why is that? Maybe `formats` is wrong? How to fix this?

How to debug this?

---

Some debugging:

I guess that `peewee` will use `pymsql` under the hood. So I tried to do this simple thing:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT publish_date FROM pub")
```

And then iterating `row in cur`, I will only get `row == (None,)`.

When casting the value beforehand to `char`, it works, i.e. I get the value as a string:

```
cur.execute("SELECT CAST(publish_date AS char) FROM pub")
```

I think this is a bug now. I reported this [here for peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1086) and [here for pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/520).

Answer (score 0):

This is a [problem/bug in pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/520) although it is not clear yet how pymysql should handle it.

For now, this monkey-patch-method fixes the problem to some degree; it will return the date as a string if it is not representable as a `datetime` object.

```
def monkey_patch_pymysql_date_fix():
    import pymysql
    orig_convert_date = pymysql.converters.convert_date
    def fixed_convert_date(obj):
        res = orig_convert_date(obj)
        if res is None:
            return obj
        return res
    pymysql.converters.convert_date = fixed_convert_date
    from pymysql.constants import FIELD_TYPE
    pymysql.converters.decoders[FIELD_TYPE.DATE] = fixed_convert_date
    pymysql.converters.conversions[FIELD_TYPE.DATE] = fixed_convert_date
```